# Haskell: How to get "\\0" into "\0"?

Tags: string, haskell, escaping

Haskell has a number of [string literals](http://book.realworldhaskell.org/read/characters-strings-and-escaping-rules.html) that use the \ escape sequence. Ones such as `\n`, `\t`, `\NUL`.

If I have the string literal:

```
let s = "Newline: \\n Tab: \\t"
```

how do I define the function `escape :: String -> String` that will convert the above string to:

```
"Newline: \n Tab: \t"
```

And the same with all other string literal escape sequences.

I'm okay with using Quasi Quoting and Template Haskell, but don't know how to use them to achieve the result. Any pointers?

---

**Update**: I just found the [Text.ParserCombinators.ReadP](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/Text-ParserCombinators-ReadP.html) module that's included in the Base library. It supports the [`readLitChar :: ReadS Char`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/Data-Char.html#v%3areadLitChar) function in Data.Char that does what I want, but I don't know how to use the ReadP module. I tried the following and it works:

```
escape2 [] = []
escape2 xs = case readLitChar xs of
    [] -> []
    [(a, b)] -> a : escape2 b
```

But this may not be the right way to use the ReadP module. Can anyone provide some pointers?

**Another update**: Thanks everyone. My final function below. Not bad, I think.

```
import Text.ParserCombinators.ReadP
import Text.Read.Lex

escape xs 
    | []      <- r = []
    | [(a,_)] <- r = a
    where r = readP_to_S (manyTill lexChar eof) xs
```

Comment: maybe you could use haskell-src (http://hackage.haskell.org/package/haskell-src) but that's probably overkill...
update: maybe (read ("\"" ++ s ++ "\"")) :: String

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You don't need to do anything.  When you input the string literal

```
let s = "Newline: \\n Tab: \\t"
```

you can check that it is what you want:

```
Prelude> putStrLn s
Newline: \n Tab: \t
Prelude> length s
19
```

If you just ask ghci for the value of `s` you'll get something else,

```
Prelude> s
"Newline: \\n Tab: \\t"
```

apparently it's doing some escape formatting behind your back, and it also displays the quotes.  If you call `show` or `print` you'll get yet other answers:

```
Prelude> show s
"\"Newline: \\\\n Tab: \\\\t\""
Prelude> print s
"Newline: \\n Tab: \\t"
```

This is because `show` is meant for serializing values, so when you `show` a string you don't get the original back, you instead get a serialized string which can be parsed into the original string.  The result of `show s` is actually displayed by `print s` (`print` is defined as `putStrLn . show`).  When you just `show s` in ghci you get an even stranger answer; here ghci is formatting the characters which are serialized by `show`.

tl;dr - always use `putStrLn` to see what the value of a string is in ghci.

**Edit**: I just realized that maybe you want to convert the literal value

```
Newline: \n Tab: \t
```

into the actual control sequences.  The easiest way to do this is probably to stick it in quotes and use `read`:

```
Prelude> let s' = '"' : s ++ "\""
Prelude> read s' :: String
"Newline: \n Tab: \t"
Prelude> putStrLn (read s')
Newline: 
 Tab:
```

**Edit 2**: an example of using `readLitChar`, this is very close to Chris's answer except with `readLitChar`:

```
strParser :: ReadP String
strParser = do
  str <- many (readS_to_P readLitChar)
  eof
  return str
```

Then you run it with `readP_to_S`, which gives you a list of matching parses (there shouldn't be more than one match, however there might not be any match so you should check for an empty list.)

```
> putStrLn . fst . head $ readP_to_S strParser s
Newline:
Tab:    
>
```

Comment: Is adding a set of quotes around a string and doing a read reliable?

Comment: @Snoqual: not entirely.  Consider a string with an embedded quotation: `"\""`.  `read` will throw a parse error in this case.  You can either add escapes to quotation characters (I would use the split package), or, since you're using string literals, test that it works with each string.

Answer (score 2):

Asking about QQ and TH means you wish to do this conversion at compile time.  For simple String -> Something conversions you can use the [OverloadedString](http://file:///Library/Haskell/ghc-7.0.3/doc/ghc-doc/users_guide/type-class-extensions.html#overloaded-strings) literal facility in GHC.

**EDIT 2** : Using the exposed character lexer in Text.Read.Lex

```
module UnEscape where

import Data.String(IsString(fromString))
import Text.ParserCombinators.ReadP as P
import Text.Read.Lex as L

newtype UnEscape = UnEscape { unEscape :: String }

instance IsString UnEscape where
  fromString rawString = UnEscape lexed
    where lexer = do s <- P.many L.lexChar
                     eof
                     return s
          lexed = case P.readP_to_S lexer rawString of
                    ((answer,""):_) -> answer
                    _ -> error ("UnEscape could not process "++show rawString)
```

**EDIT 1** : I have now got a better UnEscape instance that uses GHC's read:

```
instance IsString UnEscape where
  fromString rawString = UnEscape (read (quote rawString))
    where quote s = '"' : s ++ ['"']
```

For example:

```
module UnEscape where

import Data.String(IsString(fromString))

newtype UnEscape = UnEscape { unEscape :: String }

instance IsString UnEscape where
  fromString rawString = UnEscape (transform rawString)
    where transform [] = []
          transform ('\\':x:rest) = replace x : transform rest
          transform (y:rest) = y : transform rest
            -- also covers special case of backslash at end
          replace x = case x of
                        'n' -> '\n'
                        't' -> '\t'
                        unrecognized -> unrecognized
```

The above has to be a separate module from the module that uses unEscape:

```
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}
module Main where

import UnEscape(UnEscape(unEscape))

main = do
  let s = "Newline: \\n Tab: \\t"
      t = unEscape "Newline: \\n Tab: \\t"
  print s
  putStrLn s
  print t
  putStrLn t
```

This produces

```
shell prompt$ ghci Main.hs 


GHCi, version 7.0.3: http://www.haskell.org/ghc/  :? for help
Loading package ghc-prim ... linking ... done.
Loading package integer-gmp ... linking ... done.
Loading package base ... linking ... done.
Loading package ffi-1.0 ... linking ... done.
[1 of 2] Compiling UnEscape         ( UnEscape.hs, interpreted )
[2 of 2] Compiling Main             ( Main.hs, interpreted )
Ok, modules loaded: Main, UnEscape.
*Main> main
"Newline: \\n Tab: \\t"
Newline: \n Tab: \t
"Newline: \n Tab: \t"
Newline: 
 Tab:
```

Comment: Hi Chris. Thanks. I was hoping that I wouldn't have to reproduce the entire parsing capability of all the escape sequences in my own code.

Comment: I cannot quickly find a simple place where GHC exposes its internal parsing function.  But you could find it in GHC and copy/paste it.

Comment: What I meant is that I don't want to replicate that capability, either by implementing myself or copying. I want to use an exposed version of the built-in capability.

Comment: I have edited my answer above: I now use GHC's read instance for String.  Enjoy.

Comment: Note that the usual caveats about `read` (as I noted below my answer) would still apply.